# Can we set a limit on number of sms (text) send to a single mobile number?

Tags: twilio

Can we set a limit in Twilio to send only one message to a specific mobile number in a day?

E.g. We are using Twilio SDK to send a SMS in USA. We want to set a limitation in Twilio so that it will send only a single SMS to a mobile. If we try to send 2nd SMS to the same mobile number, it should show/return/log any error message and don't send the 2nd SMS on the same mobile number in a day. We should be able to send SMS to the same mobile number on the next day.

Answer (score 1):

This would be something you would need to code into your application. You could add some logic to your application that sends the SMS to note this send in a database for that day, then checks to see if the destination has received a message for that day (maybe through a database query when you are ready to send the next batch of SMS) and if so, not send an SMS and return some log of that event.